# Convergence to local minimum of gradient descent with exact line search for $C^1$ function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

Here is a Theorem ($3.1$) from "Introduction to Optimization" by Boris Polyak.

> > Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function and let $\{x: f(x) \le f(x^0)\}$ be compact. Let $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence generated by following procedure
> >     \begin{align*}
> > x^{k+1} = x^k - \gamma_k \nabla f(x^k),
> > \end{align*}
> >     where
> >     \begin{align*}
> > \gamma_k = \text{argmin}_{\gamma \ge 0} f\left(x^k - \gamma \nabla f(x^k)\right).
> > \end{align*}
> >     Then $\nabla f(x^k) \to 0$ and the sequence $\{x^k\}$ has limit points each of which is stationary, i.e., we can find the subsequence $x^{k_i} \to x^*$ with $\nabla f(x^*) =0$.

The proof is omitted in the book. The usually proof I have seen in the literature assumping that the gradient satisfies a Lipschitz condition, i.e., $\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \le L \|x-y\|$ for some constant $L$ and all $x, y$ and then by arguing there is some constant decrease in function value in each iteration. Combining the fact the function is bounded below, we get $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \| \nabla f(x^i)\| < \infty$ and consequently $\lim \|\nabla f(x^k)\| \to 0$.

In mimicking this kind proof, the difficulty is the decrease is not constant. Here is my attemp: If $\| \nabla f(x^k)\| \not\to 0$, then $\limsup_{k \to \infty} \|\nabla f(x^k)\| = \delta > 0$. Let $\{x^{k_j}\}$ be a subsequence realizing this limit. For each $k_j$,
\begin{align*}
f(x^{k_{j+1}}) = f(x^{k_j}) - \gamma_{k_j}^2 \|\nabla f(x^{k_j})\| + o(\gamma_{k_j} \|\nabla f(x^{k_j})\|),
\end{align*}
by Taylor expansion. Since $\nabla f(x^{k_j}) \neq 0$, $\gamma_{k_j} \neq 0$ we know that $f(x^{k_{j+1}}) < f(x^{k_j})$, we get $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \gamma_{k_j} \|\nabla f(x^{k_j})\|^2 < \infty$. But since we cannot control the stepsize, I don't know how to proceed.

Another question is why Polyak states we can find a subsequence with $x^{k_j} \to x^*$. It seems to me the sequence should be convergent to some local minimum. What am I missing here?

Comment: The vector $x^*$ is just a limit of the subsequence that  satsifies $\nabla f(x^*)=0$, it is not necessarily a global minimum (or even a local minimum).

Comment: The problem to me is since we assume some local minimum  $x^*$ exists( compact sub level set), it seems the sequence should simply converge. I don’t see the point to take a subsequence.

Comment: The function values $f(x_k)$ will be nondecreasing and will converge to a (finite) limit  as $k\rightarrow\infty$, but that does not mean $x_k$ converges to a limiting vector as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: For the proof, it would be easier to assume $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz continuous over the compact set $\{x : f(x)\leq f(x_0)\}$.  Can you assume that?

Comment: Aha, I see where I was wrong. I understand continuity in the wrong way. So the argument for the subsequence is: Since the sequence $\{f(x^k)\}$ is nonincreasing and bounded below, it must converge to some limit, that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x^k) = f^*$. By continuity, the sequence $\{x^k\}$ must be bounded, and we can extract a convergent subsequence $\{x^{k_j}\}$ with $\lim_{j \to \infty} x^{k_j} = x^*$. Then $\lim f(x^{k_j}) = f(x^*) = f^* $ where the first equality is by continuity. Is the argument OK?

Comment: We still need to show the sequence of gradient converges to $0$. As for the Lipschitz condition you mentioned, it is not assumed in the theorem. I am not sure whether we can deduce that with the conditions given.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689614/gradient-descent-for-differentiable-convex-functions

Comment: @Dap: Thanks for the reference. The example you showed is really a concrete way to know why a subsequence is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof that does not need Lipschitz continuity.

Proof: We know $\{f(x_k)\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is nonincreasing and so $x_k$ is in the compact set $C = \{x : f(x) \leq f(x_0)\}$ for all $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$.  Continuity of $f$ implies that, over this compact set $C$, there is a finite value $f_{min}$ such that $f(x_k)\geq f_{min}$ for all $k$ and so $f(x_k)$ converges to a finite value and
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} [f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)] = 0 \quad (Eq. *)$$

Suppose $||\nabla f(x_k)||$ does *not* converge to $0$ (we reach a contradiction). Hence, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $||\nabla f(x_k)||\geq \epsilon$ for an infinite number of the $x_k$ vectors.  These $x_k$ vectors are all contained in the compact set $C$, so by the Bolzano-Wierstrass theorem there is a subsequence $x_{k[i]}$ such that $||\nabla f(x_{k[i]})||\geq \epsilon$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} x_{k[i]} = z$ for some point $z\in C$. By continuity we know $||{\nabla f(z)}||\geq \epsilon$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $z$ we have for all $\gamma>0$
$$ f(z-\gamma \nabla f(z)) = f(z) + \underbrace{(\nabla f(z))^T (-\gamma \nabla f(z))}_{-\gamma ||\nabla f(x)||^2} + g(\gamma) $$
where $g$ is a function that satisfies $\lim_{\gamma\rightarrow 0^+} g(\gamma)/\gamma=0$. So there is a $\gamma^*>0$ such that $g(\gamma^*)/\gamma^* \leq ||\nabla f(z)||^2/2$ and so 
$$ f(z - \gamma^*\nabla f(z)) \leq f(z) -\frac{\gamma^*}{2} ||\nabla f(z)||^2 \leq f(z) - \frac{\gamma^* \epsilon^2}{2} \quad (Eq. **) $$
Now by the line search we have for all $i$: 
\begin{align}
f(x_{k[i]+1}) &\overset{(a)}{=}\min_{\gamma \geq 0} \left[f\left(x_{k[i]} - \gamma \nabla f(x_{k[i]})\right)\right] \\
&\overset{(b)}{\leq} f(x_{k[i]} - \gamma^*\nabla f(x_{k[i]})) \\
&= f(z- \gamma^*\nabla f(z)) + [f(x_{k[i]} - \gamma^*\nabla f(x_{k[i]})) - f(z- \gamma^*\nabla f(z))]\\
&\overset{(c)}{\leq} f(z)  -\frac{\gamma^*\epsilon^2}{2}  + [f(x_{k[i]} - \gamma^*\nabla f(x_{k[i]})) - f(z- \gamma^*\nabla f(z))]
\end{align}
where (a) holds by the line-search algorithm; (b) holds because $\gamma^*>0$; (c) holds by (Eq. **). Subtracting $f(x_{k[i]})$ from both sides of the above inequality gives
$$ f(x_{k[i]+1})-f(x_{k[i]}) \leq -\frac{\gamma^*\epsilon^2}{2}  + [f(z)-f(x_{k[i]})] + [f(x_{k[i]} - \gamma^*\nabla f(x_{k[i]})) - f(z- \gamma^*\nabla f(z))]$$
Taking a limit as $i\rightarrow \infty$ gives
$$ 0 \leq -\frac{\gamma^*\epsilon^2}{2} $$
where the left-hand-side uses (Eq. *) and the right-hand-side uses continuity of $f$ and $\nabla f$ and the fact that $x_{k[i]}\rightarrow z$. This is a contradiction. $\Box$

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I actually tried the way you gave but I tried a function $g_k(\gamma)$ in Taylor expansion for each $x_k$ and then I could not find a common $\gamma^*$. Your answer clarifies everything for me.