# Convergence rate (to a local minimum) of gradient descent for a $C^3$ function

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

> > Suppose we have a $f \in C^{3} (U)$ where $U$ is an open subset (not necessarily convex) of $\mathbb R^n$ and for some $x_0 \in U$, the sublevel set $S = \{x: f(x) \le f(x_0)\}$ is compact. Further suppose the set of local minimizers of this function is not empty and every minimizer is locally strict, i.e., for any local minimizer $x^*$, there is an open neighborhood $V \subseteq U$ of $x$, such that $f(y) > f(x)$ for all $y \in V$ and $y \neq x$. Further assume the Hessian of all local minimizers is positive definite.

I am interested to know if we start at $x_0$, the convergence rate of the sequence $\{x_k\}$ generated by  gradient descent with exact line search, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
x_{k+1} = x_k - \gamma_k \nabla f(x_k), \qquad \gamma_k = \text{argmin}_{\gamma \ge 0} f(x_k - \gamma \nabla f(x_k) ).
\end{align*}
We only consider this as a thought experiment and so we assume in every iteration, the subproblem can be perfectly solved. This is a discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689614/gradient-descent-for-differentiable-convex-functions) on the conditions to guarantee convergence for a differentiable convex function. I am putting stronger conditions and interested to know the convergence rate.

First, on the compact set $S$, $\|\cdot\| \circ \nabla^2 f: U \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and achieves maximum, so the gradient is Lipschitz. By results from convex optimization, the convergence rate should be at least $\frac{1}{k}$. Secondly, suppose $x_k \to x^*$ (might need to take a subsequence, but I think my assumptions should be enough to guarantee convergence) and by assumption every minimizer has the property $\nabla^2 f(x^*) \succ 0$. Let $F = \lambda_1 \circ \nabla^2 f$ where $\lambda_1$ is the function taking the smallest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix. $F$ should be continuous and so there must be a neighborhood $W$ of $x^*$ s.t., $F(y) > \delta > 0$ for all $y \in W$. Then it seems like the restriction $f|_W$ should be convex and indeed strongly convex, and gradient descent should converge linearly in $W$.

Is my argument correct above? And is there more we can say about the convergence of sequence $\{x_k\}$ before it entering the open set $W$?

Comment: The function $x \mapsto x^4$ has a strict $\min$ at $x=0$ but the Hessian is zero. Generally you need some sort of positive definiteness (or suitably generalised condition) to get a rate.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks. I should've thought about this example. I will modify the assumption and assume all local minimizers have positive definite Hessian. Will this be enough to talk about rate?

Comment: You should have quadratic convergence to these points then.

Comment: Why is it quadratic? I can only see linear. Also should this quadratic convergence only happens in the neighborhood $W$ as I argued above? Thanks

Comment: I think I know why it is quadratic. Is it because the exact line search will perform at least as well as Newton iteration?

Comment: My apologies. It will converge linearly. Minimising something like $(x,y) \mapsto x^2 + 2 y^2$ will show linear convergence at best. This is why we use Newton's method & variants if possible.

Comment: Sorry to ask too many questions. Is the convergence in some neighborhood or the entire sequence will converge linearly?

Comment: Without more constraints, I would say locally. You could construct an example with a saddle and two local minima, if you start on the ridge you will stay on the ridge and so never converge to either local minimum.

Comment: Suppose we are in some very ideal case. We start at $x_0$ which is not ridge or saddle. Along the path, the first critical point we met is a local minimum with positive definite Hessian. Would the entire sequence converge linearly? Outside the neighborhood $W$ I defined above, can we say something on the Hessian? If not, it seems like outside $W$, at best it would behave as gradient descent for a function with Lipschitz continuous gradient, right?

Comment: Outside of $W$ it is not clear what you can say about the Hessian. Once you enter the 'convex'  region around a local minimiser then you will hit linear convergence.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying everything. I hope this is my last question: is there some kind of sufficient condition to guarantee a local minimum having positive definite Hessian?

Comment: I am not aware of a standard one.